# algebraic properties of finite affine planes

Tags: finite-geometry

An affine plane of order $n$ has $n^2$ points, $n$ points per line, $n+1$ lines intersecting each point, every two points on one line, and $n^2+n$ lines. The plane can be partitioned into $n+1$ classes, each with $n$ parallel lines in it.

For Desarguesian planes, it is possible to represent the $n+1$ classes with the equations for lines, where multiplication and addition are in $GF(n)$:

$y=mx+b$

and $x=b$

where there are $n$ choices for $m$ and $n$ choices for $b$.

For non-Desarguesian planes, we cannot do this in $GF(n)$, but is it still possible to do something like this, so that there is still some nice algebraic structure left?

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Generalized_coordinates

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.